# Refine user taxonomy query based on role

Tags: custom-taxonomy, user-roles

I have a bunch of custom user taxonomies which I use to group users by, and then show these users on the front end with the following code (from taxonomy-{term}.php)

> ```
> <?php // Get each user from taxonomy
>             $term_id = get_queried_object_id(); // Get Term ID
>             $term = get_queried_object(); // Get term
>             $users = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $term->taxonomy );
>             if ( !empty( $users ) && (/* Condition based on role here */) ) {
>             ?>
>                 <?php foreach ( $users as $user_id ) { ?>
>                     <div class="user-card">
>                         <?php /* Image */ echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $user_id ), '204' ); ?>
>                         <h2><?php /* Name */ the_author_meta( 'first_name', $user_id ); ?> <?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $user_id ); ?></h2>
>                         <p><?php /* Short Bio */ the_author_meta( 'short_bio', $user_id ); ?></p>
>                     </div>
>                 <?php } ?>
>             <?php } ?>
> ```

The code is working just fine, but I would like to refine the results based on what role the users have. I have a role called "invisible" which lets the user access their profile but they won't be visible on the site until i change the role to one that is visible.
Ideally I would like to use something like `if (!user_has_role('invisible'))`

I've [tried](http://www.peterrknight.com/get-wordpress-user-role-by-id/) [different](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-role) [solutions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) but I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more generic version of [`current_user_can()`](http://queryposts.com/function/current_user_can/) - [`user_can()`](http://queryposts.com/function/user_can/) which takes user and capability or role to check for.

So your pseudo code would become something like:

```
if ( ! user_can( $user_id, 'invisible' ) )
```

Comment: I modified the `foreach` to this which worked perfectly. I shouldn't expect any issues?

`<?php foreach ( $users as $user_id ) if (!user_can( $user_id, 'osynlig' )) { ?>`

Comment: @talven I can't imagine this to cause any issues, it's pretty contained and informational function :)