# Exclude admin from user list

Tags: users, list

Hi i'm fairly new to PHP and Wordpress, i'm using a plugin (Users Insight) to list all users on my site.

The problem is, that i don't want to admin to appear in that list.

So far i've found the function that calls to list, but i'm not sure how to edit it so that it exclude the admin role.

```
 <?php 
    public function get_users($default_fields = null){
    global $wpdb;



    $this->build_query($default_fields);
    $results =  $wpdb->get_results( $this->query );

    $total = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' );
    $users = $this->db_rows_to_objects($results);



    $all_users = count_users();
    return array('users'=>$users, 'total'=> $total, 'alltotal'=>$all_users['total_users']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [user_can( $user_id, 'manage_options' )](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237293/check-if-user-is-admin-by-user-id) to gauge the ids in the users array and `unset($users->[$x])` the appropriate row.

I would personally use

```
$users = array();    
foreach ($results as $user)
  if (!user_can( $user->ID, 'manage_options' )) 
    $users[] = $user;
```

But that's just me.