# Hide tab Buddypress profile for visitors, not logged in users

Tags: functions, buddypress, profiles

my code below works like a charm for logged in users to hide certain tabs:

```
function bpfr_hide_activity_nav() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ){
        return;
    } 
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'media' );
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'forums' );
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'orders' );
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'activity' );
}
add_action( 'bp_ready', 'bpfr_hide_activity_nav' );
```

But for visitors/logged out users, the tabs are still visible in the members profile where role is set to Subscriber. My code is based in current_user_can, how can I transform this into profile-I-see-on-page-has-to-be-effected option?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is `bp_displayed_user_id()`. That will get the ID of the user whose profile is currently being displayed.

Then, you can [check their role like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5048/27757):

```
$user = get_userdata( bp_displayed_user_id() );
if ( ! in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    return;
}
```

You could also use `user_can()`, but it is best to [avoid using role names with `user_can()` and `current_user_can()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624), as they are really designed for capabilities and not roles. In fact, you ideally would not check user roles in a case like this at all. It would be better to add a custom capability to certain roles, like `'extended_bp_profile'`, and then check for that instead.

Comment: works like a charm @j-d, thank you very much and bounty well spend :)