# How to add a greeting message upon logging into Wordpress for certain user role

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Howzit everyone,
I have an woocommerce store with one special user role that has a discount store wide and extra discount on one category.
I used Memebers plugin to create new user role and WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing by Element Stark (for discounts).
Now I need to display a message once "Doctor" user role has logged in.
Something like:
Thank you for logging in.
You are logged in as a Doctor.
You have 17% discount store wide and 27% discount on "Morel Teas" products.
I tried to find the plugin but I can't find the plugin that will let me do this.

Comment: Include some code so that people can help you build it out... ...but as a start, what you want to do is run a conditional check on `is_user_logged_in()` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) and then you want to get the user's data and run another condition to check what the user's role is: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5048/60844

From there you can drop your pop-up code in the footer if the conditions are met and then use CSS/JS to load and display it and to allow the user to close it.