# Restricting page by user role

Tags: php, functions, customization, front-end, php.ini

I want to restrict certain pages according to user role for my wordpress site, so for example, when user with customer role wants to login to example.com/about page, they will be redirected to another page. I want to do this in software, not with a plugin, and I found the code below, but it didn't work, I think it's valid for the admin panel. How can I do the feature I said? I will be glad if you help

```php
function ts_lockout_dashboard() {
    if ( is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) );
        die();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'ts_lockout_dashboard');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer the question from beginning to end

> so for example, when user with customer role wants to login to example.com/about page, they will be redirected to another page.

> I want to do this in software, not with a plugin

Note that you can turn the snippet into a plugin by adding this to the top of the file:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: ByWorlds plugin
 */
```

Plugins are just PHP files with a comment at the top, there's not much more to them than that. People say having lots of plugins is slow for the same reason that carrying lots of things is difficult, it doesn't mean things magically get faster if you put them in your theme, just like carrying a 100lb weight is just as hard wether it's a single weight or lots of little ones.

> and I found the code below, but it didn't work, I think it's valid for the admin panel.

What it's doing is redirecting anybody who visits WP Admin who is not an administrator to `yoursite.com/login`.

Note that it uses `current_user_can` to detect if you're an admin, but that function isn't asking if you *are* an administrator, it's asking can the current user do things an admin can do, so it's not as reliable, especially when using lower level roles. [There is a better way to test if a user has a role though.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-role#5048)

> **How can I do the feature I said? I will be glad if you help**

First, we need to run this on `template_redirect`., the `init` hook is way too early, WordPress hasn't even looked at the URL, it has no idea which page you're on.

So start with this:

```php
function ByWorlds_redirects() : void {
    // redirection code
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ByWorlds_redirects' );
```

Then inside the function, check if it's WP Admin, we don't need to redirect frontend pages if we're on the backend so we'll return early and stop the check:

```php
// we only want to redirect on the frontend
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}
```

Then we need to check the users role:

[How to check if a user is in a specific role?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-role#5048)

```php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // redirects for logged out users
}

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    // The user has the "author" role, do redirects for authors
}

if ( in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    // do redirects for editors
}

// etc...
```

A lot of people might suggest using `current_user_can` for this, but this would be a mistake.

Then inside that we check the page we're on and redirect:

```php
if ( is_page('about) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_page() );
    exit;
```

or if we wanted to redirect somewhere else:

```php
if ( is_page('about) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/author_about' ) );
    exit;
```

Put these all together and you should be able to redirect any page to any other page based on the users role